# Does series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1+ \cos n}{2 + \cos n})^{2n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My idea was to test the necessary condition for the convergence of a series ($\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$). I've concluded since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos n$ doesn't exist, the necessary condition for the convergence can't be calculated, meaning that the series **diverges**. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have a hunch the sum may converge. Use the root test with the triangle inequality.

Comment: Just because the inside doesn't have a limit doesn't mean that the whole term doesn't have one.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos n$ doesn't exist.  But can you find an upper bound for $(1+\cos n)/(2 + \cos n)$ and therefore for the $n$th term of your series?

Comment: Seems like there was a similar question about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3381349/1104384

Comment: @MichaelLugo Yes, I can find the upper bound. Great hint. Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoB True, the whole term could still have a limit. Thanks for pointing that out and for pointing out the similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\in [-1,1]$:
$$0\le \frac{1+x}{2+x} = 1- \frac{1}{2+x}\le 1-\frac{1}{3} =\frac{2}{3}$$
Then
$$\left|\frac{1+\cos(n)}{2+\cos(n)}   \right|^{2n}<\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n}$$
So, the series converges

Comment: Great reply. Thanks. Does this mean that the series converges absolutely?

Comment: @AleksaMajkic Exactly

Answer (score 2):

***HINT***

Notice that

$$\Big(\frac{1+ \cos n}{2 + \cos n}\Big)^{2n}=\Big(\frac{2+ \cos n}{2 + \cos n}-\frac1{2 + \cos n}\Big)^{2n}=\Big(1-\frac{1}{2 + \cos n}\Big)^{2n}$$

but $$-1\le\cos n\le1$$

so?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This should mean that I can apply the root test here, which leads me to the conclusion that the series does converge. $\limsup\limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\limsup\limits_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{2+\cos n})^2=\frac{4}{9} < 1$